# Getting SQL queryresults filtered monthly and into excel file

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm pretty new to the sql query thing so i appoligize if i couldn't find the answer in previous threats.

This is what i'm looking for. 
I have to split an amount in location and month. 
locations are called HOST in this DB. the Month can be found in the result of a table called archiveddatetime.

What I got now is:

13 times the same query but then manually entered the where clause with a month statement.  If i do this and I have 3 differnet HOSTS it means 3x13 results to manually copy into excel. This is what i want to have automated.

This is my code so far:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)AS TotalAmountOfArchivedStudies2014BHU03
FROM   receivedstudies
WHERE  ( archiveddatetime BETWEEN '2014-01-01 00:00:00.000' AND '2015-01-01 00:00:00.000' )
       AND ( HOST LIKE 'ABC01%' );

SELECT COUNT(*)AS TotalAmountOfArchivedStudies2014BHU03
FROM   receivedstudies
WHERE  ( archiveddatetime BETWEEN '2014-01-01 00:00:00.000' AND '2014-02-01 00:00:00.000' )
       AND ( HOST LIKE 'ABC01%' );

SELECT COUNT(*)AS TotalAmountOfArchivedStudies2014BHU03
FROM   receivedstudies
WHERE  ( archiveddatetime BETWEEN '2014-02-01 00:00:00.000' AND '2014-03-01 00:00:00.000' )
       AND ( HOST LIKE 'ABC01%' );
```

I know there most be a way to put the 13 results into one query and this can be safed into excel. but perhaps also for HOST 'ABC02' and 'ABC03' in the same query.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Use `MONTH()` function ;).

Answer (score 0):

Use `GROUP BY` on `MONTH(archiveddatetime)` along with `WITH ROLL UP`

```
select HOST,MONTH(archiveddatetime),COUNT(*) As TotalAmountOfArchivedStudies
from receivedstudies
where Year(archiveddatetime) = 2014
GROUP BY HOST,MONTH(archiveddatetime)
WITH ROLLUP
```

`Rollup` will give you records with cumulative `COUNTs` as well.

Comment: Thanks ughai 
IT worked out for me with your example.